# why useState`s value does not change in this code?

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCVez.png)

height value change by setHeight() but
page value does not change by setPage()

when i use annotation code, page value change...

Comment: Well, one obvious thing to check is whether the code ever reaches setPage() since you have conditionals around it.

Comment: Don't post links to images of code on stackoverflow, copy the code and format it in the actual post.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than assuming react's `useState()` hook is not updating its value when you call the setter function, it's probably safer to assume your surrounding logic is keeping `setPage()` from being called. I would start by adding a `console.log` statement above each `setPage` call to verify whether that part of the code is being reached or not.

If the code is not being reached, then you need to revisit your logic. It looks like page increase will not be reached if:

1. $html.is(":animated")
2. e.originalEvent.deltaY <= 0
3. page == 6

Is that your intended logic? Based on your indentation after the line `if($html.is(":animated")) return;` I'm a little concerned you meant to do `if($html.is(":animated")) {` there instead. I would also suggest you might want to get out of the habit of omitting the brackets on single line if statements, this can really bite you sometimes, and may be what is causing your logic to not work as intended here.